# Adobe PhoneGap Build and WKWebView

Tags: uiwebview, adobe, wkwebview, phonegap

I have recently found an issue with videos not being able to be selected on an application I built on iOS 10.3.x. Upon doing research, it looks to be an issue with UIWebView. However, other people have suggested using WKWebView, and upon looking at Apple's website, WKWebView is the new standard, and supported on iOS 8+.

Does anyone know if Adobe PhoneGap Build default builds with UIWebView? How can I implement WKWebView, and what type of impact can it have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com/), you simply add the following to the config.xml file:

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

If you are using Angular 1.x use the following:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>

<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />


<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.16" />
```